# difference in reg ex meatcharactres like * + ? in string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, difference

can anyone explain the difference in

```
import re 

ma*n
ma+n
ma?n
```

actually the required answer is subjective but of it helps you can take examples like

```
mn  
man 
maaan   
main    
woman
```

Comment: Zero or more. One or more. Exactly zero or one.

Comment: [Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvf2P.png), it's the very first item addressed in the highest voted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`*`: presence of previous character 0 or more times (Examples 1, 2, 3)

`+`: presence of previous character 1 or more times

`?`: presence of previous character optional (0 or one time)